# $.param() date format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters

I have a form in HTML which when submitted makes a call to the server using jQuery.ajax(); like so...

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/MyArea/MyController/Search',
    data: JSON.stringify($('#myForm').serializeObject()),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
         // Output the results to a table.
    }
});
```

The MVC action it calls takes the params and sends back a load of JSON which is displayed in lovely table....it all works just fine.

I now need to introduce a button which will send back the results in a CSV format.

So I'm using the exact same method....

[1]  $('#myForm').serializeObject()

[2]  JSON.stringify the result of [1]

...but I add the step of using $.param() on the result of [2] like so....

```
window.location.replace('/MyArea/MyController/DownloadCSV?' + $.param(JSON.stringify($('#myForm').serializeObject()), true));
```

It all works fine unless dates are included the form.

Looking at fiddler I can see that the request looks like this...

```
/MyArea/MyController/DownloadCSV?referenceNo=102&startDate=01%2F04%2F2011+00%3A00&endDate=31%2F10%2F2011+23%3A59&pageNo=0&pageSize=15&sortBy=&sortDir=true
```

....and I'm getting a 500 error....

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'endDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method
```

If I remove the need for the dates then it all works just fine.

Any ideas how can I get this working?

I'm using latest jQuery with MVC3

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GET requests the default model binder expects dates to be formatted using invariant culture format. Your request should look like this:

```
/MyArea/MyController/DownloadCSV?referenceNo=102&startDate=2011-04-01&endDate=2011-10-31&pageNo=0&pageSize=15&sortBy=&sortDir=true
```

This obviously assumes that you have a corresponding controller action:

```
public ActionResult DownloadCSV(SomeViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

where SomeViewModel:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public int ReferenceNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int PageNo { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public string SortBy { get; set; }
    public string SortDir { get; set; }
}
```

Also your AJAX request seems a bit overcomplicated. You don't need to convert into JSON. The following will work just fine:

```
var form = $('#myForm');
$.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: form.attr('method'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
         // Output the results to a table.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Darin. I've re-jigged a few things and it's now working a treat.